# Android: How to store device GPS location to database?

Tags: php, android, json, gps, wampserver

I am developing two apps in which i want to get android device GPS location through one app and then using JSON with php store that location to wamp server's database, and then what i actually want is to show that location which is stored in database of wamp server on the map of second app.Can someone please guide me how to do this and what logic should i use. Thanks

Comment: if you have the location response, what is stopping you to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials on net if you google it. But it sounds like you haven't done your homework. By the way here you can get some help. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3